# how to get date value from Jspinner excluding time

Tags: java, jspinner

i have a Jspinner which shows current date("yyyy//mm//dd" in this format) and i want to get only current date not time,when i use System.out.println(Spinner.getvalue()).It also shows time like this(Mon Sep 09 02:47:53 IST 2013).i just want current date 2013/09/08

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [JSpinner javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html#getValue%28%29):

> `public Object getValue()`
>
> Returns the current value of the model, typically this value is
>   displayed by the editor. If the user has changed the value displayed
>   by the editor it is possible for the model's value to differ from that
>   of the editor, refer to the class level javadoc for examples of how to
>   deal with this.
>
> This method simply delegates to the model. It is equivalent to:
>
> `getModel().getValue()`

This means when you call `getValue()` method you'll get a `java.util.Date` object (since you're using `SpinnerDateModel` I guess). When you use `System.out.println(Spinner.getvalue())` the output shows the default `toString()` implementation from `java.util.Date` class which is long and includes the time.

If you want to show the date in this format `yyyy/mm/dd` try this:

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(spinner.getValue()));
```

Note: don't get confused about `java.util.Date` object and its `String` representation.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that you need to use some date converting tool like SimpleDateFormat.

```
SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
String spinnerValue = formater.format(Spinner.getvalue());
System.out.println(spinnerValue);
```

All SimpleDateFormat info and date patterns can be found here: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html